# Displaying Dynamic Circle in html page using SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The below code is a simple form that accepts a number from the user and dispalys a circle of the radius entered in the form. Everything is working fine except that the circle vanishes as soon as I click on the submit button. How to fix this? I want the circle to be there long after I clicked on the submit button.

```
<title>Dynamic Vector Circle</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  

    function createCircle()
    {
        var myCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle"); //to create                                          a circle, for rectangle use rectangle
        var radius= document.getElementById("rad").value;
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"id","mycircle");
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",100);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",100);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",radius);
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
        myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");

        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle).innerHTML;
    }                 

</script>
```

```
<form>   
    <input type="text" id="rad" placeholder="Enter radius">
    <button onClick="createCircle();">Submit</button>

    <svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>

</form>
```

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior with JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/252yLdqx/

Comment: @Cymen, your code not inside `form` as in OP

Comment: @Sachin, by default button do _submit_ on click, are you sure that you need do submit? if not - use `type="button"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the default action for a form on a button click is to submit. To avoid submitting, you can `return false` from the function bound to the button. So if you change the end of `createCircle` to:

```
  ...
  return false;
}
```

It will work as you desired. Here is the whole function:

```
function createCircle()
{
    var myCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle"); //to create                                          a circle, for rectangle use rectangle
    var radius= document.getElementById("rad").value;
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"id","mycircle");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",100);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",100);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",radius);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","none");

    document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle).innerHTML;

    return false;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/252yLdqx/2/

Or you can change the `button` to an `input` with `type="button"` which will not have the default behavior to submit the form:

`<input type="button" id="create" value="Create"/>`

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/252yLdqx/3/

Or you can change the `button` to have `type="button"` to override the default `type="submit"` like so:

`<button type="button" onClick="createCircle();">Submit</button>`

Or you can not enclose the inputs within a `form` tag and do whatever you would like!

Comment: `<button type="button">` also valid, not need change it to input

Comment: It is working fine in JSFiddle. But when I open the .html file in the Chrome browser, the circle is not getting rendered. Can you suggest what might be the problem for not rendering?

Comment: @Grundy Thanks -- I'll add that too.

Comment: @SachinBS, are you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: @SachinBS Are you bring the code from JSFiddle back to your example? If so, on JSFiddle, I had to hook up the button with JS so make sure the button on your HTML has the onClick property like this one: `<button onClick="createCircle();" type="button">Submit</button>`.

Comment: Thank You so much. The circle is being rendered perfectly now.